# Echo url from an array which contains $string

Tags: arrays

I have an array with some urls. I want to echo the url which contains the $string. for the moment I only echo "match found". here is the code :

```
`$string="test";
$people = array(domain.com/test-2.html, "domain.com/2.html", "Glenn", "domain.com/3.html");
if (in_array($string, $people))
{echo "Match found";}
else {echo "Match not found";}`
```

thanks

Comment: Your description isn't very clear, it looks like you simply want to `echo $string;` instead of `echo "Match found";`

Comment: sorry, I want to display the url which contains $string. in my example, I would like the echo of "domain.com/test-2.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually you misunderstood how in_array works when you do :

```
$string="test";
$people = array("domain.com/test-2.html", "domain.com/2.html", "Glenn", "domain.com/3.html");

if (in_array($string, $people)) {
    echo "Match found";
}
else {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

It should always echo "Match not found" if $string is not exactly equals to one of the people value (e.g. `$string = "domain.com/test-2.html"`).

If you want to find a subset of string ("test") in an array the easiest way is to itarate through the values and comparing with strpos :

```
$string="test";
$people = array("domain.com/test-2.html", "domain.com/2.html", "Glenn", "domain.com/3.html");

$found = false;
foreach ($people as $url) {
    if (strpos($url, $string)) {
        echo "Match found : " . $url; # Or just : echo $url;
        $found = true;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

Example testable here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b0c39c9493c5731a847d36c4b3ed85686cc21c6b